# How to run django with apache in a docker container correctly

Tags: django, docker, apache, docker-compose

So I'm been trying to dockerized my Django app with apache on a container and I keep getting this error
`Invalid command 'WSGIProcessGroup', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`

I tried to install mod_wsgi with apt and pip but the result was still the same

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM httpd:2.4

ADD ./requirements.txt ./
RUN apt-get update \
&& apt-get install -y \
python3-pip python3-venv \
libapr1 libapr1-dev \
libaprutil1-dev \
libapache2-mod-wsgi \
&& python3 -m venv /.cp \
&& /.cp/bin/pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt \
&& rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

The requirements.txt

```
django
mod-wsgi
psycopg2-binary
djangorestframework
markdown
django-filter
```

my custom vhost file

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    serverAdmin svenikia@taskmaster.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/webapp"
    Servername www.webapp.io
    ServerAlias webapp.io
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/access.log" combined
    Alias /static /capstone/static
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/webapp/static">
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/webapp/webapp">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>
    WSGIProcessGroup webapp_project
    WSGIDaemonProcess webapp_project python-path=/webapp python-home=/.env
    WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/webapp/webapp/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is my docker compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
        postgres:
                image: postgres:13.1-alpine
                environment:
                        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
                        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
                        POSTGRES_DB: parking
                restart: always
                container_name: db
        apache:
                build : ./Django
                image: web:1.0
                container_name: web
                ports:
                        - "8080:80"
                volumes:
                        - ./my-httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
                        - ./Django/web.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
                        - ./Django/web:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/my-web
networks:
        default:
                external:
                        name: network
```

At first my initial idea was to have 3 containers, one for postgres, the second for django and the third for apache. But after many fail attemps, I just go with 2 containers one for postgres and the other for generating virtualenv, django app and apache. Any help would be great, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you did is right but it missing some custom things :

1. First of all you need to link your django static file to the apache web server and to do that you need to add a service on your docker-compose.yml for the django part .

after that **using volume** you can link the django output as **an input for apache**

For more details thanks to follow this [example](https://realpython.com/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/)

Comment: Thanks, mate, I will try to follow the example above, if I success I will mark your solution

Comment: you are welcome , the goal is that you can resolve your issue .